# C# UDP socket not receiving message from correct port

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, udp

I created a test driver to simulate an issue I'm having with another program:
EDIT2: This code can be largely ignored and the second block of code may be more succinct

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace TestAsyncSockets
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Object to send back and forth along with datagrams
        /// </summary>
        class State
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Socket that started async receive
            /// </summary>
            public Socket S;

            /// <summary>
            /// Endpoint that data was received from
            /// </summary>
            public EndPoint E;

            /// <summary>
            /// Buffer where received data is stored
            /// </summary>
            public byte[] Buffer;
        }

        private const int SERVER_PORT = 50000;

        private const int SERVER_CMD_SEND_PORT = 50001;

        private const int CLIENT_PORT = 50002;

        private static readonly IPAddress s_LocalHost = new IPAddress(new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1});

        private static readonly StringBuilder s_Logger = new StringBuilder();

        private static readonly object s_Locker = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Test async sockets
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            // Server receives commands on SERVER_PORT from anyone and calls CommandReceived
            CreateReceiver(s_LocalHost, SERVER_PORT, IPAddress.Any, 0, ServerCommandReceived);

            // Client receives Acks on CLIENT_PORT from SERVER_PORT and calls ResponseReceived
            CreateReceiver(s_LocalHost, CLIENT_PORT, s_LocalHost, SERVER_PORT, ClientResponseReceived);

            // Client receives commands on CLIENT_PORT from SERVER_CMD_SEND_PORT and calls 
            CreateReceiver(s_LocalHost, CLIENT_PORT, s_LocalHost, SERVER_CMD_SEND_PORT, ClientCommandReceived);

            // Client sends commands from CLIENT_PORT to SERVER_PORT
            CreateSender(s_LocalHost, CLIENT_PORT, s_LocalHost, SERVER_PORT, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ClientCmd"));

            // Server sends commands from SERVER_CMD_SEND_PORT to CLIENT_PORT
            CreateSender(s_LocalHost, SERVER_CMD_SEND_PORT, s_LocalHost, CLIENT_PORT, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ServerCmd"));

            // Wait for messages to be received (hack for test code only)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\log.txt", s_Logger.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(s_Logger.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a socket to send data
        /// </summary>
        private static void CreateSender(IPAddress localIp, int localPort, IPAddress remoteIp, int remotePort, byte[] dataToSend)
        {
            // Create socket for sending
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            // Allow other Sockets to bind to its local end point
            sender.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            // Create local end point and bind to it
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localIp, localPort);
            sender.Bind(localEndPoint);

            // Create remote end point to send to
            EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(remoteIp, remotePort);

            // Send and log
            sender.SendTo(dataToSend, remoteEndPoint);
            string message = string.Join("", Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(dataToSend));
            LogStatement("Sent " + message + " from " + localEndPoint + " to " + remoteEndPoint);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates socket to receive a message and call async method
        /// </summary>
        private static void CreateReceiver(IPAddress localIp, int localPort, IPAddress remoteIp, int remotePort, AsyncCallback messageReceived)
        {
            // Create UDP socket
            Socket receiver = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            // Create local endpoint to bind to
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localIp, localPort);

            // Allow other Sockets to bind to this local end point too
            receiver.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            // Bind to local endpoint
            receiver.Bind(localEndPoint);

            // Create remote endpoint
            EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(remoteIp, remotePort);

            // Create state object for async callback
            State receiveState = new State { S = receiver, E = remoteEndPoint, Buffer = new byte[100] };

            // Begin receiving message from remote endpoint
            // Call messageReceived callback when done
            receiver.BeginReceiveFrom(receiveState.Buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ref remoteEndPoint, messageReceived, receiveState);
            LogStatement("Receiving on " + localEndPoint + " from " + remoteEndPoint + " and will call " + messageReceived.Method.Name);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method called when server receives command
        /// </summary>
        private static void ServerCommandReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            LogStatement("In ServerCommandReceived");
            State state = (State)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                int bytes = state.S.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref state.E);    // End recieve and get data
                if (bytes > 0)
                {
                    byte[] actualMessage = new byte[bytes];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(state.Buffer, 0, actualMessage, 0, bytes);
                    string message = string.Join("", Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(actualMessage));
                    LogStatement("Received " + message + " on " + state.S.LocalEndPoint + " from " + state.E);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                LogStatement(se.ToString());
            }

            // We just received a command. Send a response back to the port that sent the command (state.E)
            state.S.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Response"), state.E);
            LogStatement("Sent " + "Response" + " from " + state.S.LocalEndPoint + " to " + state.E);

            state.S.BeginReceiveFrom(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref state.E, ServerCommandReceived, state);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method called when client receives a command response
        /// </summary>
        private static void ClientResponseReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            LogStatement("In ClientResponseReceived");
            State state = (State)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                int bytes = state.S.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref state.E);
                if (bytes > 0)
                {
                    byte[] actualMessage = new byte[bytes];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(state.Buffer, 0, actualMessage, 0, bytes);
                    string message = string.Join("", Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(actualMessage));
                    LogStatement("Received " + message + " on " + state.S.LocalEndPoint + " from " + state.E);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se.ToString());
            }

            state.S.BeginReceiveFrom(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref state.E, ClientResponseReceived, state);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method called when client receives a server command
        /// </summary>
        private static void ClientCommandReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            LogStatement("In ClientCommandReceived");
            State state = (State)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                int bytes = state.S.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref state.E);
                if (bytes > 0)
                {
                    byte[] actualMessage = new byte[bytes];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(state.Buffer, 0, actualMessage, 0, bytes);
                    string message = string.Join("", Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(actualMessage));
                    LogStatement("Received " + message + " on " + state.S.LocalEndPoint + " from " + state.E);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                LogStatement(se.ToString());
            }

            state.S.BeginReceiveFrom(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref state.E, ClientCommandReceived, state);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Thread safe logging (hopefully)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s"></param>
        private static void LogStatement(string s)
        {
            lock (s_Locker)
            {
                s_Logger.AppendLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit verbose but it's mostly comments. I can remove those if people would prefer.

Anyway, down to business. Looking at this quickly, I would expect ServerCommandReceived, ClientResponseReceived, and ClientCommandReceived to each be called once, but when I run it, I see ServerCommandReceived called once and ClientResponseReceived called twice. What appears to be happening is that ClientResponseReceived, is being called when messages are received from 50001 OR 50002. Why is this happening? Is it not possible to have two UDP sockets bound to the same port listening for messages from two remote UDP ports?

EDIT:
Just for clarification, the output of the program is:
Receiving on 127.0.0.1:50000 from 0.0.0.0:0 and will call ServerCommandReceived
Receiving on 127.0.0.1:50002 from 127.0.0.1:50000 and will call ClientResponseReceived
Receiving on 127.0.0.1:50002 from 127.0.0.1:50001 and will call ClientCommandReceived
Sent ClientCmd from 127.0.0.1:50002 to 127.0.0.1:50000
Sent ServerCmd from 127.0.0.1:50001 to 127.0.0.1:50002
In ServerCommandReceived
Received ClientCmd on 127.0.0.1:50000 from 127.0.0.1:50002
Sent Response from 127.0.0.1:50000 to 127.0.0.1:50002
**In ClientResponseReceived

Received ServerCmd on 127.0.0.1:50002 from 127.0.0.1:50001**
In ClientResponseReceived
Received Response on 127.0.0.1:50002 from 127.0.0.1:50000

The bold text is the issue. ServerCmd should have been received in the callback "ClientCommandReceived".

Also, I tried using Connect() and BeginReceive/Send instead of BeginReceiveFrom/SendTo and that didn't work. And it doesn't allow connecting to IPAddress.Any or port 0, so I had to hack it to even get that far.

EDIT2:
I updated the code to the following for succinctness:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestAsyncSockets {
    static class CProgramSuccinct {
        // Class for async receives
        class State {
            public Socket S;
            public EndPoint E;
            public byte[] Buffer;
        }

        private static readonly IPAddress s_LocalHost = new IPAddress(new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1});
        private static readonly StringBuilder s_Logger = new StringBuilder();
        private static readonly object s_Locker = new object();

        static void Main() {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\log.txt", "");
            SetupReceivers();
            SendCommands();

            // Wait for messages to be received (hack for test code only)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\log.txt", s_Logger.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(s_Logger.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SendCommands() {
            List<Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint>> endpointPairs = new List<Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint>> {
                new Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint>(
                    new IPEndPoint(s_LocalHost, 50002), new IPEndPoint(s_LocalHost, 50000)), // client sends command from 50002 to 50000
                new Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint>(
                    new IPEndPoint(s_LocalHost, 50001), new IPEndPoint(s_LocalHost, 50002)), // server sends command from 50001 to 50002
            };

            foreach (Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint> endpoints in endpointPairs) {
                Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                sender.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                sender.Bind(endpoints.Item1);

                sender.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Command"), endpoints.Item2);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                LogStatement("Sent Command from " + endpoints.Item1 + " to " + endpoints.Item2);
            }
        }

        private static void SetupReceivers() {
            List<Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint>> endpointPairs = new List<Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint>> {
                new Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint>(
                    new IPEndPoint(s_LocalHost, 50000), new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)), // server receives commands on 50000 from anywhere
                new Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint>(
                    new IPEndPoint(s_LocalHost, 50002), new IPEndPoint(s_LocalHost, 50000)), // client receives responses on 50002 from 50000
                new Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint>(
                    new IPEndPoint(s_LocalHost, 50002), new IPEndPoint(s_LocalHost, 50001)), // client receives commands on 50002 from 50001
            };

            // Callbacks for each async receive
            List<AsyncCallback> receiverCallbacks = new List<AsyncCallback> { ServerCommandReceived, ClientResponseReceived, ClientCommandReceived };

            int i = 0;
            foreach (Tuple<IPEndPoint, IPEndPoint> endPoints in endpointPairs) {
                Socket receiver = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                receiver.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                receiver.Bind(endPoints.Item1);

                State receiveState = new State { S = receiver, E = endPoints.Item2, Buffer = new byte[100] };

                receiver.BeginReceiveFrom(receiveState.Buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ref receiveState.E, receiverCallbacks[i], receiveState);
                LogStatement("Receiving on " + endPoints.Item1 + " from " + endPoints.Item2 + " and will call " + receiverCallbacks[i].Method.Name);
                i++;
            }
        }

        private static void ServerCommandReceived(IAsyncResult ar) {
            State state = LogMessage(ar, "ServerCommandReceived");

            // We just received a command. Send a response back to the port that sent the command (state.E)
            state.S.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Response"), state.E);
            LogStatement("ServerCommandReceived: Sent " + "Response" + " from " + state.S.LocalEndPoint + " to " + state.E);
            state.S.BeginReceiveFrom(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref state.E, ServerCommandReceived, state);
        }

        // The client doesn't send responses
        private static void ClientResponseReceived(IAsyncResult ar) { LogMessage(ar, "ClientResponseReceived"); }
        private static void ClientCommandReceived(IAsyncResult ar) { LogMessage(ar, "ClientCommandReceived"); }

        // logs received message
        private static State LogMessage(IAsyncResult ar, string methodName) {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            State state = (State)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytes = state.S.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref state.E);
            if (bytes > 0)
            {
                byte[] actualMessage = new byte[bytes];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(state.Buffer, 0, actualMessage, 0, bytes);
                string message = string.Join("", Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(actualMessage));
                LogStatement(methodName + ": Received " + message + " on " + state.S.LocalEndPoint + " from " + state.E);
            }

            state.S.BeginReceiveFrom(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref state.E, ClientCommandReceived, state);
            return state;
        }

        private static void LogStatement(string s) {
            lock (s_Locker) {
                s_Logger.AppendLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just to make it shorter for the post and something strange happened:

```
Receiving on 127.0.0.1:50000 from 0.0.0.0:0 and will call ServerCommandReceived
Receiving on 127.0.0.1:50002 from 127.0.0.1:50000 and will call ClientResponseReceived
Receiving on 127.0.0.1:50002 from 127.0.0.1:50001 and will call ClientCommandReceived
Sent Command from 127.0.0.1:50002 to 127.0.0.1:50000
ServerCommandReceived: Received Command on 127.0.0.1:50000 from 127.0.0.1:50002
ServerCommandReceived: Sent Response from 127.0.0.1:50000 to 127.0.0.1:50002
Sent Command from 127.0.0.1:50001 to 127.0.0.1:50002
ClientResponseReceived: Received Command on 127.0.0.1:50002 from 127.0.0.1:50001
ClientCommandReceived: Received Response on 127.0.0.1:50002 from 127.0.0.1:50000
```

Now I see each receive method called once! Unfortunately, I'm still confused because ClientResponseReceived should be called when messages are received from 50000 and ClientCommandReceived should be called when messages are received from 50001 but they are switched. Not sure if this is a reference issue or a Windows socket thing.

Comment: UDP is more similar to a broadcast protocol, similar to a Radio Station it just sends content for any receiver to pick up.  Therefore your description that you are receiving the same packet twice is cause by two receivers listening.   Other than "Directed Broadcasting" if you want to determine a peer to peer relationship it would be done at application layer as UDP (if I remember correctly) doesn't implement that concept.

Comment: @JohnPeters sorry for the confusion. I'm not receiving the same message twice. I'm receiving two messages on the same receiver when I would expect one receiver to receive one message and the other receiver to receive the other. If UDP is more like broadcast, then is the C# "SendTo" method a lie?

Comment: @JohnPeters, I think it is possible to listen on specific port using UDP.